# Onclick not firing in latest Qt Webkit example

Tags: javascript, qt, webkit

Using that latest Qt 5.1.2, a button onclick event is not firing when run on a Windows 8 touchscreen. Using Qt 5.0, it fires just fine.

To reproduce, just create the html5application test app and change your index.html to be this (ie, add the button and the onclick handler). When built against 5.0 and run on a Windows 8 tablet, when you touch the button you see the javascript alert. When compiled against the latest Qt, 5.1.2, you don't get any feedback.

Any ideas on anything I'm doing wrong? Is this is a bug or a feature in the latest Qt?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <style type="text/css">
        body { margin: 0; font-size: 2em; background-color: white; }
        h1 { text-align: center; color: red; }
        h1 + h1 { color: green; }
        h1:last-child { color: blue; }
        #quit { background-color: gray; color: white; font-weight: bold; display: block; text-align: right; }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var counter = 0;
        function toggleElement()
        {
            var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('h1');
            for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; ++i)
                elements[i].style.display = (counter % elements.length) == i ? '' : 'none';
            counter++;
            setTimeout('toggleElement()', 1000);
        }
        window.onload = function()
        {
            document.getElementById("quit").onmousedown = function()
            {
                Qt.quit();
            };
            toggleElement();
        }
        function clicked()
        {
            alert("Clicked");
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <a id="quit">X</a>
    <h1>Hello</h1>
    <h1>HTML5</h1>
    <h1>World</h1>
    <p><button type="button" onclick="clicked()">Click Me!</button></p>
</body>
</html>
```